# How to solve Python SyntaxError:in if call while posting dB data to kml with variable-determined map icons?

Tags: python, ms-access, anaconda, kml, jupyter-lab

I want to use Python to query data out of a MS Database every 5 minutes and post it into a kml to be viewed by multiple people via network link. I get to the end of the code where I am trying to use the if elif to determine which placemark icon is displayed per row result. Here is my sample code:

```
import simplekml
kml = simplekml.Kml()
pnt = kml.newpoint(name="cpeMAC", coords=[(cpeLON,cpeLAT)])
pnt.description = "FullAddress","Network"
pnt.snippet.content = "cpeMAC","cpeStatus"
pnt.snippet.maxlines = 1
pnt.lookat = simplekml.LookAt(gxaltitudemode=simplekml.GxAltitudeMode.relativetoseafloor,
latitude= cpeLAT, longitude= cpeLON, 
range=3000, heading=56, tilt=0) 
# The above range, heading and tilt should be hard coded. 
# The icon’s for each placemark should change based on the values in cpeStatus. There are 5 output types that can be passed from the dB: None, Off, Repair, Active, Alarm. 

# Below is the code that I need the most help with 

if  cpeStatus = 'Active':
    pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/ranger_station.png"
    
    elif cpeStatus = 'Off':
        pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/forbidden.png"
        elif cpeStatus = 'Ready':
            pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/mechanic.png"
            elif cpeStatus = 'Alarm':
                pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/caution.png"
                return stat

# The file should then be saved to kml stored on the local server. 
kml.save("PremiseCPEStatus3.kml")
```

I am getting the following consistent error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-24-49c8d14fb0c8>", line 26
    if  cpeStatus = 'Active':
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

For reference, the database query is successfully pulling the following information:
I separated the rows with a  space to make it easier to read

```
('124-22-A9-12-44-88', 'Alarm', '32.622399444', '-83.60337837', '365 Johns Rd, Warner Robins, GA 31093', 'eCommunity Warner Robins')  
('34-E6-AD-E5-AC-77', 'Alarm', '32.621384', '-83.620274', '606 McArthur Blvd, Warner Robins, GA 31093', 'eCommunity Warner Robins')  
('36-E6-AD-E5-AC-77', 'Off', '32.623730', '-83.620145', '365 Johns Rd, Warner Robins, GA 3109', 'eCommunity Warner Robins')  
('68-F7-28-ED-12-FA', 'Ready', '32.624298', '-83.627544', '112 Anne Dr, Warner Robins, GA 3109', 'eCommunity Warner Robins')  
('00-FF-A8-F3-3D-28', 'Active', '32.620851', '-83.630560', '410 Bernard Dr, Warner Robins, GA 3109', 'eCommunity Warner Robins')  
(None, None, '32.623577', '-83.628145', '101 Gordon St, Warner Robins, GA 3109', 'eCommunity Warner Robins')
```

Comment: `=` → assignment; `==` → comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error:

> File "", line 26 if cpeStatus = 'Active': ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

should be:

`if cpeStatus == 'Active'`

otherwise, you're assigning during an if statement rather than checking its value, invalid syntax.

Also, I'd consider something a little more readable. I would structure it something like this (you don't need to indent since it's all testing the same var)--

```
icon_status = {
    'Active': 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/ranger_station.png',
    'Off': 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/forbidden.png'
    'Ready': 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/mechanic.png',
    'Alarm' 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/caution.png'
}

if  cpeStatus = 'Active':
    pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href = icon_status['Active']
elif cpeStatus == 'Off':
    pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href = icon_status['Off']
elif cpeStatus == 'Ready':
    pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href = icon_status['Ready']
elif cpeStatus == 'Alarm':
    pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href = icon_status['Alarm']
return stat
```

Comment: I incorporated the above code and had to make a few corrections such as cpeStatus == 'Active' versus just one =. I also had to define elements using "cpeStatus" etc. Below is the updated code:

Comment: I ran into the following error at the end: File "<ipython-input-16-e92cddccf449>", line 42
    return stat
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: I solved the problem but created a new problem. Creating an If change while trying to pull into kml was causing an issue with the simplekml module. Therefore I created a new field in the database and included the Placemark type thus reflecting in the KML output.